# condition is satisfied but it doesn't run the codes

Tags: vb.net

```
If (need_1a.Text <= ava_4a.Text) And (need_1b.Text <= ava_4b.Text) And (need_1c.Text <= ava_4c.Text) Then
            ava_5a.Text = Convert.ToInt32(ava_4a.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(need_1a.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(max_1a.Text)
            ava_5b.Text = Convert.ToInt32(ava_4b.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(need_1b.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(max_1b.Text)
            ava_5c.Text = Convert.ToInt32(ava_4c.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(need_1c.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(max_1c.Text)
            need1 = 4
        ElseIf (need_5a.Text <= ava_4a.Text) And (need_5b.Text <= ava_4b.Text) And (need_5c.Text <= ava_4c.Text) Then
            ava_5a.Text = Convert.ToInt32(ava_4a.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(need_5a.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(max_5a.Text)
            ava_5b.Text = Convert.ToInt32(ava_4b.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(need_5b.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(max_5b.Text)
            ava_5c.Text = Convert.ToInt32(ava_4c.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(need_5c.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(max_5c.Text)
            need5 = 4
        End If
```

i have this code, the first condition is satisfied but it doesn't run the code.

[image: deadlock app]

Comment: You should set `OPTION Strict on` and learn to program strongly typed. You should also use `AndAlso` instead of `And`, otherwise you are always evaluating all conditions even if the first one already returned `False`.

Comment: Did you try debugging, is the code hit?

Comment: use break points in the code and test if the condition is really satisfied, also I am not sure with the logic here, u r using ava_Xa texts and evaluating it inside on right side of equal sign as well

Comment: yes, i tried debugging but it doesn't get to the codes while in fact the values satisfy the condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Val ()`

Without val() its a string comparision.

```
    If (Val(need_1a.Text) <= Val(ava_4a.Text)) And (Val(need_1b.Text) <= Val(ava_4b.Tex)t)
    And (Val(need_1c.Text) <= Valava_4c.Text)) Then

       ava_5a.Text = Convert.ToInt32(ava_4a.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(need_1a.Text) + 
       Convert.ToInt32(max_1a.Text)
       ava_5b.Text = Convert.ToInt32(ava_4b.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(need_1b.Text) +
       Convert.ToInt32(max_1b.Text)
       ava_5c.Text = Convert.ToInt32(ava_4c.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(need_1c.Text) + 
       Convert.ToInt32(max_1c.Text)
       need1 = 4

   ElseIf (Val(need_5a.Text) <= Val(ava_4a.Text)) And (Val(need_5b.Text) <= 
   Val(ava_4b.Text)) And (Val(need_5c.Text) <= Val(ava_4c.Text)) Then

       ava_5a.Text = Convert.ToInt32(ava_4a.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(need_5a.Text) + 
       Convert.ToInt32(max_5a.Text)
       ava_5b.Text = Convert.ToInt32(ava_4b.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(need_5b.Text) + 
       Convert.ToInt32(max_5b.Text)
       ava_5c.Text = Convert.ToInt32(ava_4c.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(need_5c.Text) + 
       Convert.ToInt32(max_5c.Text)
        need5 = 4

   End If
```